# Numpy C-Api change ordering from column to row major

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, cython

What is the best way to change the ordering of a numpy array when passing it to a c extension? For the interface I'm using cython with numpy's `PyArray_DATA`

Let's say I have `x = np.empty((2000,10))` and I want to pass that array to C such that `x[2000]` corresponds to `x[0,1]` in python and `x[1]` to `x[1,0]`.
How would I do that?

So far I tried various combinations of `np.copy(oder='C')`, `np.transpose()`, `np.reshape((-1))` and `np.flatten`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the terms column and row major. `Row-major` is `order='c'` and `Column-major` is `order='f'`. Here is an example to show aht

```
shape = (2000, 10)
buffer = "".join("{:5d}".format(i) for i in range(np.prod(shape)))
x = np.ndarray(shape, 'S5', order='f', buffer=buffer)
print x[0, 1]
# ' 2000'
print x.flags
#   C_CONTIGUOUS : False
#   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   OWNDATA : False
#   WRITEABLE : False
#   ALIGNED : False
#   UPDATEIFCOPY : False
x = np.ndarray((2000, 10), 'S5', order='c', buffer=buffer)
print x[0, 1]
# '    1'
print x.flags
#   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   F_CONTIGUOUS : False
#   OWNDATA : False
#   WRITEABLE : False
#   ALIGNED : False
#   UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

There are a few ways to force a memory layout in numpy, here are some:

```
# When you create the array:
x = np.empty((2000, 10), order='f')

# Check the order and copy if needed:
x = np.asfortranarray(x)

# Force a copy:
x_fortran = x.copy(order='f')
```

Note that all 3 of these methods will produce a numpy array that is "the same", ie will look the same to all python code:

```
print np.all(x.copy('c') == x.copy('f'))
# True
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My specific problem arises because the array in question is interpreted as (2000,10) in the python part of the program but because of performance reasons the array should be interpreted as (10,2000) in the C extension. What I basically need is some way of forcing a change in the way the array is stored in memory.

Comment: Sounds like you want to force a "fortran" layout. Any of the 3 methods in my answer should get you what you need.